# System.Drawing not supported with ASP NET CORE & Electron EDGE JS

Tags: asp.net-core, electron, system.drawing, edgejs

We are building an app(Actually converting) with electron & asp net core in which we came across an issue
"**System.Drawing is not supported on this platform.**". We are using Electron EdgeJS for making server side call from electron app.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-edge-js

In our product system.drawing assembly needed as that forms the core of the app. Without system.drawing assembly we could able to connect to server via Electron-Edgejs.

And it's actually working fine in MVC where we dont run into any issues.

Electron Edge

```
var getAppDomainDirectory = edge.func({
    assemblyFile: baseDll,
    typeName: localTypeName,
    methodName: 'GetAppDomainDirectory'
});
```

C#

```
public async Task<object> GetAppDomainDirectory()
{
Image image1 = Image.FromFile(@"Capture.png");
Image image2 = Image.FromFile(@"signature.jpg");
PropertyItem propItem = image1.GetPropertyItem(20624);
propItem.Id = 20625;
image2.SetPropertyItem(propItem);
return "";
}
```

Exception Snippet

[image]

Comment: Did you try switching to this Nuget: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-do-you-use-systemdrawing-in-net-core ?

Comment: We already tried, it doesn't help.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to overcome or alternate if any?

Comment: You will have to put more info here about it, like the code, including your usings, the content of the exception, etc'

Comment: check this article: https://photosauce.net/blog/post/5-reasons-you-should-stop-using-systemdrawing-from-aspnet

Comment: @o_w Added exception snapshot